# WebSQL/SQLite calculating distance using latitude and longitude?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I have a PhoneGap app and have shifted everything to a local DB, I now need to calculate the users location form the points in the DB.

Does anyone have any pointed how to do this, I was using the Google API but now focusing on this working offline so have to query the DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to calculate the distance from longtitude and lattitude (offline), right??

[Look at this link](http://www.paulproduction.com/calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-offline/)

```
var lat1 = //start latitude
var lon1 = //start longitude
var lat2 = //end latitude
var lon2 = //end longitude

var R = 6371; // now in km (change for get miles)
var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
var d = R * c;

if (d>1)
    return Math.round(d);//+"km";
else if (d<=1)
    return Math.round(d*1000)+"m";

return d;
```